# Lens Flare strange rotation while rotating camera

Tags: three.js

While rotating camera, lens flare has some rotation based on camera angle, please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4kf3u7t/1/

I want to avoid that, making lens flare always facing camera without rotation, like Sprite behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/e4kf3u7t/3/

Sample code:

```
var flareColor = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
var lensFlare = new THREE.LensFlare( textureFlare0, 200, 0.0, THREE.NormalBlending, flareColor );
lensFlare.position.y = 100;
lensFlare.position.z = 200;
scene.add(lensFlare);
```

The reason why I want to use Lensflare instead of Sprite is as you can see in fiddle, lens flare disappearing when it center hiding behind another geometry, Sprite doesn't act like that.

Comment: Lens flares are dependent on camera and object position. If it doesn't rotate to look at the camera, it feels a bit unreal. Why do you want it to stay fixed?

Comment: That not what i means, it's still facing the camera, but I want rotate behavior like Sprite, please compare above 2 fiddle then you'll see the different.

Comment: I know they're different. What I'm saying is, the way it is (1st fiddle) feels right. Why do you want to apply an unrealistic behaviour (2nd fiddle)?